# How can I make the first letter of a variable always capital?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Capitalize the first letter of string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript)

I am making something called "The HTML Quiz". It's made with JavaScript. When the user first enters it, they have to enter their name. Once they click submit, the name they enter is saved into a variable. It doesn't look nice when it says:

> Dear nathan,
>
> You are about to take The HTML Quiz. Please.....

I think it looks better like this:

> Dear Nathan,
>
> You are about to take The HTML Quiz. Please.....

But if the user enters their name starting with a lowercase letter, it will stay that way. Is there anyway to make that first letter turn into an uppercase letter if it is lowercase **with jQuery**?

For example, here is a simple name enter script: http://jsfiddle.net/RcLt6/

If you enter your name in all lowercase, of course, it will be all lowercase. How can I make the first character entered always be capitalized no matter what?

Comment: This is answered well in [this Stack Overflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, as I didn't want to lowercase all letters, only the first one.

Comment: @Nathan: But it's called "Capitalize the first letter of string in JavaScript".

Comment: @Tomalak Oh, I see what you mean. I was just looking at the first answer on there.

Comment: .. which is called "capitaliseFirstLetter", and capitalises the first letter... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it:

```
str = str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qNJVQ/

---

Btw, put the INPUT inside the LABEL - that way you won't have to use the `for` attribute to associate the label with the input field:

```
<label>
    Name: <input type="text">
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I just replace `str` with `name`? (`name` is the variable that holds the name value)

Comment: @Nathan Be aware that `[]` notation on strings doesn't work in IE7 and IE6, so if you care about those browsers you should go with `str.charAt(0)` instead of `str[0]`.

Comment: @Šime Thanks, but I don't really care about IE 8 and down lol. My project doesn't support those. Only IE 9, Firefox, Safari, Google Chrome, etc. (basically all of the **good/modern browsers** are supported) Most of the viewers will be using non-IE browsers anyway so it wont really matter. Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: Use standard-compliant syntax. And don't wrap `<input>` inside `<label>` like that: it's a tempting piece of laziness, but it's not portable... nor semantic.

Comment: @Tomalak But `str[0]` is standard-compliant - it's in ES5. I must admit I'm not able to find it in the ES5 spec `:)`, but [Mozilla states it is in ES5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#section_5), and also kangax lists it as an ES5 feature in [his ES5 table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).

Comment: @Tomalak Could you elaborate how it's not portable?

Comment: @Sime: I vaguely remember it not working in IE something-or-other.

Comment: On checking, both _are_ indeed standard-compliant.